# Animate.css add animation on click

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, animate.css

I want to animate an image input when the user click the image, I'm using `animate.css` with Bootstrap and Angular, I've seen some examples to add the animate class when the image is click but nothing happens, when I console.log the element in the function I can see that the animate class is added but didnt work, also I got an error message in the console.

**html code**

```
<input type="image" src="../../../assets/img/as-logo-150dpi-05.png" class="d-block animate__animated animate__slideInLeft" id="offMenu" (click)="animateLogo()">
```

**TS code**

```
animateLogo(){
    const element = document.querySelector('#offMenu');
    if(element) {
      element.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__bounceOutRight');
      console.log(element)
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the input class, the aniimate class "animate__bounceOutRight" is added but nothing happens in my project, any advice on this?

So after the answer I found out the error message is because of bootstrap, nothing to do with the animation, and the problem was because the input already have an animation, when the function added another this overlaps and didint make it work so I need to disable the first one to make the second works but now the input disappear because of the second animation

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" src="../../../assets/img/as-logo-150dpi-05.png" class="d-block animate__animated animate__slideInLeft" id="offMenu" [ngClass]="{'animate__slideInLeft ': firstAnimation , 'animate__bounceOutRight': secondAnimation }" (click)="animateLogo()">
```

**TS**

```
firstAnimation: boolean; //This is true
 secondAnimation: boolean; //This is false
    
 animateLogo(){
    this.firstAnimation = false
    this.secondAnimation = true
  }
```

Comment: You might like to see [this](https://kodingkhurram.github.io/animate.css-dynamic.demo/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the `animate.css` styles in your

`angular.json`

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/animate.css/animate.css"
  ],
```

*OR*

`styles.css`:

`@import '~animate.css/animate.min'`

Also just for a better approach let's try to do tackle your problem the Angular way

In your `.ts` create a boolean field named `activateAnimation` and we'll set it as `true` when the user clicks the image so your .ts code will look something like this:

```js
  activateAnimation: boolean;
    
  animateLogo(): void {
     this.activateAnimation = true
  }
```

and then in your HTML we can conditionally add the `animate.css` classes that you want to add using the `[ngClass]` directive of Angular.

````html
<input type="image" src="../../../assets/img/as-logo-150dpi-05.png"
    class="d-block animate__animated animate__slideInLeft"
    [ngClass]="{'animate__animated ': activateAnimation , 'animate__bounceOutRight': activateAnimation }" id="offMenu"
    (click)="animateLogo()">```
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this wasnt working but I found out is because the input already have a animated class, so base on your answer I use 2 variables for the 2 different animations and work out but now when the second animation that is the bounceOutRight applies to the input, this disappear because of the animation so what do you think I can do to show again the input after the animation ends? I update my question with the answer you gave me

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a little research I found a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLNk3pzMFCI) that explains how to use `Animate.css` using `jQuery` and using the function that he explains with the click event I managed to take out the first animation class, add the second one and once the animations ends, take out the second animation class and add again the first animation class, all of this in the TS file, have some problems coding the jQuery in the TS file but the framework helps me out with the correct form of the code

So first in my `<input>` I added the `class offMenu` to identify my input, also I leave the `animate__animated` so I dont have to add it every time I take out or add an animation class and also I leave the `animate__slideInLeft` because I want to animate the `input` the first time ther page loads.

```
<input type="image" src="../../../assets/img/as-logo-150dpi-05.png" class="d-block animate__animated animate__slideInLeft offMenu" id="offMenu">
```

Next in my TS file in the constructor part I code the jQuery function, I create 3 variables:

- The first one is `effects` this variable saves the second effect that
  is `animate__bounceOutRight`.
- The second variable is `effectsEnd` that saves the different classes
  that Animate.css have to detect when the animation ends for the
  different browsers.
- And the third one is to save the element I want to add or remove
  classes, in this case is my `input` with the `class offMenu`.
- If you want to add one more variable to save the animate class you currently have, you can do it.

Next I select the element I want to add and remove classes and call the event `on click` once again in the function I select the element and remove the firts animate class `'animate__slideInLeft'` as this animation already end theres no need to add the `effectsEnd` variable, next I add the second animation class that is saved in my variable `effects`, then with `one` we indicate this is going to happen one time and check fot the animation to end with the variable `effectsEnd` once the animation ends, we remove the animation class `effects` and add the firt animation class.

```
    constructor() {   
        $(() =>{

      var effects = 'animate__bounceOutRight';
      var effectsEnd = 'animationend oAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd webkitAnimationEnd';
      var element = $('input.offMenu');

      $(element).on("click", () => {

        $(element).removeClass('animate__slideInLeft').addClass(effects).one(effectsEnd, () =>{
            $(element).removeClass(effects).addClass('animate__slideInLeft')
          });
      });
    })
  }
```

Whit this code you can put one animation to show when the page is load and then add another animation when you click in the element and take back the element once the out animation is done, hope this helps someone else.